# Tikhonov regularization

Tags: matrix

I am looking at some code that adds `Tikhonov regularization` to an autocorrelation `matrix`.

Like this:

```
double power = (matrix[1][1] + matrix[2][2]);
float factor = 0.000136 //Found via trial and error

for(i = 1; i < matrixSize; i++ )
{
    matrix[i][i] += ( factor * power );
}
```

I am stuck in understanding what that `power` means, why has the second and third parts of the diagonal been used?  How is this even helping make the numbers more stable?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a math question and not a programming problem.

If you have issues understanding the Tikhonov regularization, you probably should post on https://math.stackexchange.com/